# TFF : Difference between split clients into train and test or split each client dataset into train and test

Tags: tensorflow-federated

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.12488.pdf) paper, the authors choose 2500  training clients and 900 clients for evaluation

but in this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification), they split the dataset of each client into training and test. So, I would like to know which is better ? and what is the importance of spliting clients into training and evaluation ?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

"Which evaluation method is better" depends on the question the investigator is trying to answer. Both hold-out users (the paper), and hold-out examples (the tutorial) can provide different information about the model and training process.

The paper focuses on how *global model accuracy* relates to *personalized model accuracy*. The *personalized accuracy* is measuring how well each client's local model performs on the clients local data. In this scenario, each client ends up having a *different* model.

The tutorial is only investigating the first part, the *global model accuracy*, without continuing to personalize the models locally for each client.

In practical settings its not always possible to personalize a model (some clients may have no data), and some personalization strategies may make the model worse for the given client. However, as the paper demonstrates, a working personalization strategy can have a significant improvement on *local client accuracy*.